# Error in Custum Dialect Hibernate 3?

Tags: java, hibernate

its showing some error like : INSTANCE cannot be resolved or is not a field for(TextType.INSTANCE.getName()).

This is my Custom Dialect:

```
package com.bdisys.promorphics.dialect;

import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect;
import org.hibernate.type.TextType;

public class MyCustumSQLDialect extends MySQLDialect {

    public MyCustumSQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerHibernateType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, TextType.INSTANCE.getName()); 
      }

}
```

Comment: You are getting this error in you IDE?

Comment: yes am getting it in my IDE i think its because of some import statement....i dont know exactly..

Comment: You are probably using a version of hibernate that doesn't have this static field. What version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: i am using hibernate 3 version...and tell me what is the alias to this in hibernate 3??

Comment: I told you what to do in the answer. you can download release 3.6 and use the same API.

Comment: oops!!the project is showing an error again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not using the right hibernate version. 3.5 does not have the instance field http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/TextType.html while 4.1 does http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/TextType.html.

BTW, if you don't want to use version 4, use 3.6 that do have this field.